# Analogous functions for Erdas Autosync in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

We have two overlapping rasters with some shifting occurring as below image:

[image: overlapping rasters]

and we need to eliminate the shifting in the overlap zone, so the rasters align like in the below image:

[image: shifted rasters]

In Erdas Imagine we can use the `Autosync` function to make this correction, are there analogous functions in QGIS?

Comment: If QGIS cannot do it and you need to investigate a third software then ask a separate question.